# Cnodeput offcentered when using fractions

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

Here is the following code:

```
\documentclass[multi,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(2,2)
\Cnodeput[radius=.7](1,1){a}{$\dfrac{a_b}{a}$}
\psdot(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The circle is offcentered when using Cnodeput, but it is correctly centered when using cnodeput. How can this be fixed without using magic numbers?

Edit: with the new pst-node.tex.

```
\documentclass[multi,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(2,2)
\pnode(1,1){cat}
\cnodeput(cat){cat}{$\dfrac{a_b}{a}$} %works
\Cnodeput[radius=.7](cat){meow}{$\dfrac{a_b}{a}$} %works
\Cnodeput[radius=.7](cat){cat}{$\dfrac{a_b}{a}$} %does not work
\psdot(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: A fixed file `pstricks.tex` is here: 
http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/generic/pstricks/
You need also the old `pst-node.tex` http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/generic/pstnode/

Will also be on CTAN in the next days.

```
\documentclass[multi,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](2,2)
    \pnodes(1,1){cat}
    \cnodeput(cat){cat}{$\dfrac{a_b}{a}$}
    \Cnodeput[radius=.7](cat){cat}{$\dfrac{a_b}{a}$} 
    \Cnodeput[radius=.9](cat){cat}{$\dfrac{a_b}{a}$}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see new edit. There looks to be another bug.

Comment: No, that is the default behaviour. You used a node name cat for the coordinates and also define a new node with the same name. Use something like `\Cnodeput[radius=.9](cat){cat2}{$\dfrac{a_b}{a}$}`

Comment: O I see. Why does `(cat){cat}` work for `\cnodeput`?

Comment: it works different. However, I'll put it on the todo-list

Comment: See my edited answer. The problem was in `pstricks.tex` and not in `pst-node.tex`

Answer (score 0):

I defined a `\myCnodeput` command, which accepte an optional argument. I added `auto-pst-pdf`  which allows compiling with `pdflatex`, provided you use the `--enable-write18` switch (for MiKTeX) ot `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX):

```
\documentclass{standalone}%
\usepackage{pstricks-add,amsmath}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\myCnodeput{or()mm}{%
\rput(#2){#4}\Cnodeput[#1](#2){#3}%
}%
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(2,2)
\myCnodeput[radius=0.7, linecolor=red](1,1){b}{$\dfrac{a_b}{a}$}
\psdot(1,1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need Cnodeput though to get a specific radius.

Comment: Ah! That's different. I'll try to think of a solution.

Comment: @cat: Please see my updated answer.